# How to ignore SSL check while using com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest

Tags: java, ssl, httprequest

I am using com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest object to hit a URL for Akamai Purge. However, I am getting an SSL Handshake error but as it is in a lower environment so I am allowed to ignore this. There are multiple examples on the internet ignoring SSL Handshake for Spring REST Template and Apache HTTPRequest. But I could not find much on google HttpRequest. I need a way to ignore SSL Cert in my code. Below is my code:

'''

**HttpTransport httpTransport = new ApacheHttpTransport();**

**HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory();**

**URI uri = URI.create(url1);**

**String requestBody = "{\"objects\": [471642]}";**

**HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl(uri),**

**ByteArrayContent.fromString("application/json", requestBody));**

**GoogleHttpClientEdgeGridRequestSigner requestSigner = new**
**GoogleHttpClientEdgeGridRequestSigner(credential);**

**requestSigner.sign(request);**

**HttpResponse response = request.execute();**

'''

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971951/11226302. There is an option doNotValidateCertificate() that you can use apparently!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it. Thanks Shivam Puri. I used below code

'''

ApacheHttpTransport.Builder transBuilder = new ApacheHttpTransport.Builder();
        ApacheHttpTransport  httpTransport  =

transBuilder.doNotValidateCertificate().build();

'''